# determining lunar eclipse with SPICE toolkit

Tags: spice

Is there any way to determine if the Sun is visible from the Moon at a given latitude/longitude and at a given instant in SPICE toolkit? Specifically, determine if there is lunar eclipse or transit and if so, how much of the solar disk is shaded by the Earth? Or do i have to do it myself from the position vectors?

Comment: I believe you are looking for the gfoclt function: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/cspice/gfoclt_c.html
Example 1 in that documentation is how to calculate the solar eclipses for the Moon